# Why is atomic number is more or less the same as number of neutrons for light elements?

Tags: nuclear-chemistry, neutrons

In periodic table, the atomic weight is more or less twice the proton number. Do neutrons naturally tend to be in similar quantity as protons? I know atomic weight weighted average of isotopes but why this more or less a trend if we move across the periodic table we find atomic weight is 2(protons) + $\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ < 2

Comment: It is true for light elements only. E.g. 238U contains 92 protons and 238-92=146 neutrons. See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semi-empirical_mass_formula  and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nuclear_shell_model

Comment: While an interesting question, you are basically asking about nuclear physics and how it works. Too many protons and the nucleus wants to fly apart - the neutrons help stabilize the nucleus. But, too many neutrons and one can beta emit and become a proton.

Comment: As mentioned, it's a physics question, but in brief, Maria Goeppert Mayer won a Nobel Prize for her work on a nuclear shell model. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(physics)  for a start.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik alright I can accept that an answer.

Comment: @Poutnik, yes, i did mean light elements. There is some order to light elements that I need to explore. I guess DrMoishe's reference might be great aid to understanding why is this the case.

Comment: @JonCuster I see. Thats a nice gist of whats happening. I guess its something to do with Magic numbers as DrMoishe mentioned here.

Comment: Your title is not the same as your question...